# Injeção de Dependência - Dois objetos que implementam uma mesma interface

Tags: java, spring, interface, injeção-de-dependência

Tenho dois objetos das classes AmazonS3UploadService e o DatabaseUploadService e ambas implementam a interface UploadService. A Classe que faz upload tem os dois objetos injetados pelo container do Spring.

O problema é que o container não consegue injetar as dependências corretamente e ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
 Can not set br.com.manager.domain.service.AmazonS3UploadService field br.com.manager.domain.service.ConfiguracaoService.amazonS3UploadService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67
```

Tentei usar outras anotações como `@Resource, @Inject, @Qualifier` e atualmente uso `@Autowired`

Obs: Sei que não é uma boa colocar arquivos no banco de dados, por vários motivos, mas como é um projeto com finalidade de estudo, coloquei como opção.

Comment: Não sei se dá para configurar a injeção, mas se você está injetando as duas implementações, a algo de errado. Injeção de dependência tem como motivação principal você só ter um local para criar as instancias que implementam interface. Se o consumidor *realmente* precisa das duas implementações, use interfaces diferentes ou (mais sensato) elimine a injeção de dependência para este consumidor e esses serviços: não faz sentido centralizar a dependência se vai usar várias implementações.

Comment: @RSinohara Analisei o código depois do que você falou e percebi que realmente é preciso mudar e não faz sentido ter duas implementações injetas.

Comment: Faz sentido ter um código que determina qual implementação vai ser injetada, estilo plugin. Mas injetar ambas realmente não imagino caso onde seja necessário/útil.

Comment: Eu criei uma interface e a implementação da interface que vai verificar para onde o arquivo vai. E na classe que usava os dois objetos eu coloquei a nova implementação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você está injetando as duas implementações, há algo de errado.

Injeção de dependência tem como motivação principal você só ter um local para criar as instancias que implementam cada interface.

Se o consumidor realmente precisa das duas implementações, use interfaces diferentes ou (mais sensato) elimine a injeção de dependência para este consumidor e esses serviços: não faz sentido centralizar a dependência se vai usar várias implementações.

Answer (score 0):

Por mais que injetar as duas implementações no mesmo ponto do sistema seja estranho, o problema não teve a ver com isso. Você provavelmente pediu a injeção usando atributos do tipo concreto, enquanto deveria ter usado a interface como tipos dos atributos. Dessa forma, bastava você colocar o @Qualifier em cima de cada um dos atributos que a injeção seria feita corretamente.

Alberto